# Creating a "hole" with 0 opacity inside a container with color - css on react native (Layout for a QR scanner)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native-camera so I could scan QRs, this works fine.
On top of the camera I would like to have white color with opacity and on the middle of the screen there should be a blank square to indicate that the user should scan the QR in the middle.
I am struggling to do this because when I put the white screen layout on top than of the blank square than the blank square is not seen. When I put the blank square on top of the layout then because the blank is with opacity 0 it is not seen.

How can I create a screen where there is a color for the whole screen but a "Hole" in the middle of it?

To help you understand exactly what I need, this is where I am at right now:

[image]

I need for the part inside the border to have 0 opacity

Comment: white not simple a black square? it should be seen everywhere?

Comment: What do you mean? I still need the inside of the square to have 0 opacity - just showing the camera as it is.

Comment: ah so you mean the inside to be transparent?

Comment: You need SVG, I believe.

Comment: @Temani Ali yes

Answer (score 4):

Use a giant `box-shadow` on your chosen centered element.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 5vh;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Not working in react-native. No box shadow. There is shadow that does not work for android so this is not a solution for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I solved it eventually by using SVG. This is for anyone that happens to stumble here.

I used react-native-svg in order to create the background and a mask for the "Hole":

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: deviceWidth,
    height: deviceHeight,
},
layout: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: deviceWidth,
    height: deviceHeight,
    zIndex: 2,
},
camera: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: deviceWidth,
    height: deviceHeight,
    zIndex: 1,
}
```

})

```
const QrScannerLayout = () => (
<View style={styles.layout}>
    <Svg height="100%" width="100%">
        <Defs>
            <Mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
                <Rect height="100%" width="100%" fill='white' opacity={0.8} />
                <Rect
                    x={(deviceWidth / 2) - (QR_SCAN_SQUARE_SIZE / 2)}
                    y={(deviceHeight / 2) - (QR_SCAN_SQUARE_SIZE / 2)}
                    rx='50'
                    ry='50'
                    width={QR_SCAN_SQUARE_SIZE}
                    height={QR_SCAN_SQUARE_SIZE}
                    stroke='white'
                    strokeWidth="5"
                    fill-opacity="0"
                />
            </Mask>
        </Defs>
        <Rect height="100%" width="100%" mask="url(#mask)" fill='white' />
    </Svg>
</View>
```

);

```
    render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <QrScannerLayout />
            <RNCamera
                ref={ref => {
                    this.camera = ref;
                }}
                captureAudio={false}
                onBarCodeRead={this.barcodeRecognized}
                style={styles.camera}
            >
            </RNCamera>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:
put this in your customMarker property

```
import {Dimensions} from "react-native";

let devicewidth=Dimensions.get("window").width
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <QRCodeScanner 
                showMarker            
                customMarker={
                    <View style={{flex:1}}>
                        <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"}}/>
                        <View style={{width:devicewidth,
                            height:devicewidth,
                            borderColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0.3)",
                            borderWidth:devicewidth/6,
                        }}>
                            <View style={{flex:1,borderColor:"red",borderWidth:1}}/>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"}}/>
                    </View>
                }/>
         </View>
     )
}
```

then you can set the size of the hole on the borderWidth property(`borderwidth:devicewidth/{how big you want the hole to be}`)